# Aurelia iterate over map where keys are strings

Tags: aurelia

I'm having trouble getting Aurelia to iterate over a map where the keys are strings (UUIDs).

Here is an example of the data I'm getting from an API running somewhere else:

```
my_data = {
  "5EI22GER7NE2XLDCPXPT5I2ABE": {
    "my_property": "a value"
  },
  "XWBFODLN6FHGXN3TWF22RBDA7A": {
    "my_property": "another value"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to use something like this:

```
<template>
<div class="my_class">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li repeat.for="[key, value] of my_data" class="list-group-item">
                <span>${key} - ${value.my_property}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

But Aurelia is telling me that `Value for 'my_data' is non-repeatable`.

I've found various answer by googling, but they have not been clearly explained or incomplete. Either I'm googling wrong or a good SO question and answer is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another resource to the one supplied by ry8806, I also use a Value Converter:

```
export class KeysValueConverter {
  toView(obj) {
    if (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object') {
      return Reflect.ownKeys(obj).filter(x => x !== '__observers__');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

It can easily be used to do what you're attempting, like this:

```
<template>
<div class="my_class">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li repeat.for="key of my_data | keys" class="list-group-item">
                <span>${key} - ${my_data[key]}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method would be to convert this into an array yourself (in the ViewModel code)

Or you could use a ValueConverter inside `repeat.for` as described in this article [Iterating Objects](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/08/iterating-objects-using-repeat-for-in-aurelia/)

The code...

```
// A ValueConverter for iterating an Object's properties inside of a repeat.for in Aurelia
export class ObjectKeysValueConverter {
    toView(obj) {
        // Create a temporary array to populate with object keys
        let temp = [];

        // A basic for..in loop to get object properties
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
        for (let prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                temp.push(obj[prop]);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
}

/**
 * Usage
 * Shows how to use the custom ValueConverter to iterate an objects properties
 * aka its keys.
 * 
 * <require from="ObjectKeys"></require>
 * <li repeat.for="prop of myVmObject | objectKeys">${prop}</li>
 */
```

OR, you could use the [Aurelia Repeat Strategies](https://github.com/martingust/aurelia-repeat-strategies) provided by an Aurelia Core [Team member](https://github.com/martingust)

You'd have to import the plugin into your app.
Then you'd use it using the pipe syntax in your **repeat.for**....like so....

```
<div repeat.for="[key, value] of data | iterable">
    ${key} ${value.my_property}
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful. I like the plugin, but am always looking for a way to avoid extra dependencies, where possible. While your ValueConverter example was useful, I ended selected @LStarky's answer only because it was more complete in producing my desired output.